# Uninstalling app not delete app group data .Do I have to remove app group container and it's content manually?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension, ios-app-group

I created a `Today Extension` that is introduced in iOS 8 first time. To share data between `Today extension` and it's `container App`, I defined an `app group`, and bind them to this group. (Actually I added an embedded framework also to re-use code in both side.)

Details of this method is described in [Apple's document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html).

I created some core data model and store it as sqlite on group container. Then everything works as I thought.

However, when I uninstall container app, There are still shared container and it's content on my iPhone. I think when last member of app group is uninstalled, this container should have to be deleted automatically. In my case, members of app group are shipped with just a single app, So, uninstalling this app should have to clear shared container.

Am I wrong?

ps. I could not find a way to delete this shared container as an user. Only developer who has rights to access app-group can remove this container with programming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In iOS8 beta 4, App group container is deleted automatically when the last app that is belongs to the group is uninstalled,

So, it was just a bug that is now fixed by Apple.

Comment: Not fixed here with Xcode 6 GM. Deleting app does not remove its app container data on the simulator.

Comment: Is there any documentation to back this up?

Comment: It is mentionned here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1412643-containerurlforsecurityapplicati?language=objc at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

As precised inside the documentation of [containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfilemanager/1412643-containerurlforsecurityapplicati?language=objc) (behavior is different whether you are on macOS or iOS)

> Unlike in macOS, when all the apps in a given app group are removed
> from the device, the system detects this condition and removes the
> corresponding group directory as well.

So the answer to your question is no.