# Removing App doesn't remove App Group data

Tags: ios, ios-app-group

Ever since I started using App Groups to share Core Data between my App and a Today Extension/Widget I am having an issue. When I delete my app the core data maintains on the device, instead of being deleted like it used to.

I am aware this question has been asked before: [Uninstalling app not delete app group data .Do I have to remove app group container and it's content manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158410/uninstalling-app-not-delete-app-group-data-do-i-have-to-remove-app-group-contai)

The answer says it was a bug and Apple fixed it. I however still have the problem with iOS 9.2

How can I make sure that removing my app also removes the Core Data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So in the end, I figured it out. A very old version of the app(Made with a different framework) was still installed on the test device, which happened to have the same App group.

Comment: Yeah, just discovered this, somehow once all apps that is in the AppGroup gets deleted, then the AppGroup data will be deleted.