# Is it good approach to keep database in AppGroup's shared container

Tags: ios, swift, realm, ios-app-group

I am using Realm in my application as database and i am having share extension to support media to be share from other application. Since i need my database to be accessed from share extension i moved realm file from App's document directory to Appgroup's shared container. I have below questions.

1. Is it safe to store the database in shared container space.
2. When i uninstall the app, still files inside shared container persist, so when the shared container will be deleted.
3. Any other best practices to handle my scenario.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that you cross-posted this in Realm's GitHub issue tracker. My comment from https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4899#issuecomment-297121059 reposted here for your convenience:

> > 1. Is it safe to store the database in shared container space.
>
> Yes. In fact it's the only way to share files across processes on iOS.
>
> > 2. When i uninstall the app, still files inside shared container persist, so when the shared container will be deleted.
>
> According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/25027088/373262, iOS deletes shared containers once the last app to have access to it is removed from the device.
>
> If you find situations in which this doesn't happen, I encourage you to file a radar to inform Apple about the bug. https://bugreport.apple.com
>
> > 3. Any other best practices to handle my scenario.
>
> Sounds like you're doing everything right. Keep it up!

---

In the future, please don't cross-post questions on StackOverflow with the `realm` tag as well as Realm's GitHub repos. The Realm engineering team monitors both of these channels, so your question will be answered even if you just post it once.